# Programmatically name FILEGROUP in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that will create a new FILEGROUP based upon a given date parameter. What I want to see is a FILEGROUP called something like '2010_02_01'. What I get is a FILEGROUP called '@PartitionName'.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CREATE_DATE_FILEGROUP] @PartitionDate DATETIME
AS
DECLARE
    @PartitionName VARCHAR(10);
BEGIN
    SET @PartitionName = REPLACE(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @PartitionDate, 120), 10), '-', '_');
    ALTER DATABASE MSPLocation ADD FILEGROUP [@PartitionName];
END
```

Comment: There are alternatives to creating filegroups on the fly when partitioning, you can re-use existing ones if organised correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to end up having to using sp_executesql to execute it, something like

```
declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
setl @sql = 'ALTER DATABASE MSPLocation ADD FILEGROUP[' + @PartitionName + ']'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: We've taken your advice and settled upon an alternative to creating them on the fly but thanks for this answer too.

Comment: Have a read of http://sqlfascination.com/2009/10/15/guidance-on-how-to-layout-a-partitioned-table-across-filegroups/ for some guidance / ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @FileGroupName sysname
SET @FileGroupName = 'Foo'

EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase ADD FILEGROUP [' + @FileGroupName + ']')
```

Think about SQL injection, though.

Comment: The parameter is coming in declared a datetime, so injection is not going to occur.